# Time sampling changes solution

Tags: ode, computational-physics, scipy, numerics

I'm currently trying to solve a problem using numerical methods. The set-up is rather long, so I apologize in advance...

**TL;DR**: My solutions change depending on how big my steps are and I don't know why.

---

**Set-up**

The first part of this problem can be described by a Lagrangian $L(s,\theta)$, which is given by
$$L = \frac{1}{24}(L^2\dot\theta^2+4b^2\dot\theta^2+24s\dot\theta^2+12\dot s^2+ 12 b\dot s \dot\theta+24gs\sin\theta -12bg\cos\theta).$$
This Lagragian gives, by means of the Euler-Lagrange equations,
$$
\begin{align*} 
 \dot\theta^2 +g \sin\theta &=\ddot s + \frac{1}{2}b\ddot\theta\\ 
\left(\frac{1}{12}L^2+\frac{1}{3}b^2\right)\ddot\theta+\frac{1}{2}b\ddot s &= \frac{1}{2}bg\sin\theta-2\dot s\dot\theta-gs\cos\theta, 
\end{align*}
$$
where you can assume $L=0.1,\,b=0.02$ and $g=9.81$.
I also have the initial conditions given by:
$$s(0)=0.1,\quad \dot s(0)= 0.3,\quad u(0)= 0,\quad \dot u(0)= 0.$$
The generalized coordinates $s,\theta$ and the real trajectory are connected over
$$x = \begin{pmatrix}s\cos\theta + \frac{b}{2}\sin\theta\\ -s\sin\theta +\frac{b}{2}\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}.$$

The first part of the problem is to solve this set of differential equation up to the time $t^*$ when the condition $\ddot x(t^*) = 0$ is fulfilled, or in terms of $s$ and $\theta$ until we have
$$-2 \sin\theta(t^*) \dot s(t^*)\dot\theta(t^*) - \cos\theta(t^*) s(t^*)\dot\theta^2(t^*) - \frac{1}{2}b\sin\theta(t^*) \dot\theta^2(t^*) + \cos\theta(t^*) \ddot s(t^*) + \frac{1}{2} b\ddot\theta \cos\theta(t^*) -s(t^*) \ddot\theta(t^*) \sin\theta(t^*) \overset{!}{=} 0.$$
After this time $t^*$ the new trajectory is given by

$$\vec{x}= \begin{pmatrix}x\\ - \left[x\tan(|\alpha|)+\frac{gx^2}{2v_0\cos^2(|\alpha|)}\right]\end{pmatrix} \quad\text{and}\quad \theta(t)= \dot \theta(t^*) \cdot t + \theta(t^*)$$ 
where $\alpha = \theta(t^*)$ and $v_0 = \dot s(t^*)$.

---

My attempt to solve this goes as follows: First defined
$$y = \begin{bmatrix}s\\\dot s\\ \theta\\ \dot\theta\end{bmatrix} \Longrightarrow \dot y = \begin{bmatrix}\dot s\\\ddot s\\\dot \theta\\ \ddot\theta\end{bmatrix}$$
I solved the Euler-Lagrange eq. for $\ddot \theta$ and $\ddot s$ and inserted them into $\dot y$ which gives `rhs`

```
def rhs(y, t, g=9.81, L=0.01):
    return np.array([y[1], 
                    (1/(b**2 + L**2 + 24.0**y[0]**2))*
                    (6.0*b*g*np.cos(y[2])*y[0] - 7.0 *b**2 *g*np.sin(y[2]) - g* L*2.0 *np.sin(y[2]) - 24.0 *g *y[0]**2*np.sin(y[2]) 
                        - 24.0*b* y[0]* y[1]* y[3] - 8.0* b**2* y[0] * y[3]**2 - 2.0* L**2* y[0]* y[3]**2 - 48.0*y[0]**3* y[3]**2), 
                    y[3], 
                    -12.0*(-g *np.cos(y[2]) * y[0] + b* g* np.sin(y[2]) + 4* y[0] * y[1]* y[3] + b *y[0] *y[3]**2)/(b**2 + L**2 + 24 *y[0]**2)
                    ])
```

I then used `scipy`'s `odeint`algorithm to solve the problem in the follwoing way

```
T = np.linspace(0,10,10000)
b = 0.02
lstart = 0.02
ystart = np.array([np.sqrt(lstart**2+ (b/2.0)**2), v, 0.0, 0.0])
y, data = odeint(rhs, ystart, T, full_output = True, args=(g, L))
```

This worked out and plotting the solutions gives results that I expected.

The next thing to do was to figure out $t^*$. For this I interpolated the solutions and inserted them into the defining condition to find $t^*$. The following function is supposed to return the index of `T` at which this happens

```
def find_tstar_index(T, y):
    # Find point where bread leaves table
    s_spl = UnivariateSpline(T, y[:, 0], s=0, k=4)
    u_spl = UnivariateSpline(T, y[:, 2], s=0, k=4)



    s_spl_d = s_spl.derivative(n=1)
    s_spl_2d = s_spl.derivative(n=2)

    u_spl_d = u_spl.derivative(n=1)
    u_spl_2d = u_spl.derivative(n=2)

    searching_for_zeros = -2.0*np.sin(u_spl(T))*s_spl_d(T)*u_spl_d(T) \
                        - np.cos(u_spl(T))* s_spl(T)* u_spl_d(T)**2 \
                        -1/2.0* b* np.sin(u_spl(T))*u_spl_d(T)**2  \
                        + np.cos(u_spl(T))*s_spl_2d(T)\
                        + 1/2.0* b* np.cos(u_spl(T))* u_spl_2d(T) \
                        - s_spl(T)*np.sin(u_spl(T))*u_spl_2d(T)

    tstar_index = np.where(searching_for_zeros < 1e-25)[0][0]
    return tstar_index

tstar_index = find_tstar_index(T, y)
```

The next step would be to set up $\vec{x}$ and $\theta (t)$ using $t^*$

The actual problem starts here: I now definie the follwoing function

```
angle = lambda t: y[tstar_index, 3] * t + y[tstar_index, 2]
```

The thing is now that depending on the `T` defined in the beginning of my code the function `angle` changes significantly. For example

```
T_A = np.linspace(0,1,10000)
T_A = np.linspace(0,10,10000)
```

give completely different results for the intervall [0,1] when plugged into the respective `angle` function... There has to be an error in my logic but after hours of trying to figure out what the problem is I'm kind of lost...

---

**Complete Code**

I'll post down here my complete code so that you can try it out yourself, but up to line 142 everything seems to work fine (`T_fall` is the same array regardless of what `T` is...)

```
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline

g = 9.81
L = 0.1
#T = np.linspace(0,10,10000)
b = 0.02
lstart = 0.02
table_hight = 1.3

vs = [0.7]

def find_tstar_index(T, y):
    # Find point where bread leaves table
    s_spl = UnivariateSpline(T, y[:, 0], s=0, k=4)
    u_spl = UnivariateSpline(T, y[:, 2], s=0, k=4)



    s_spl_d = s_spl.derivative(n=1)
    s_spl_2d = s_spl.derivative(n=2)

    u_spl_d = u_spl.derivative(n=1)
    u_spl_2d = u_spl.derivative(n=2)

    searching_for_zeros = -2.0*np.sin(u_spl(T))*s_spl_d(T)*u_spl_d(T) \
                        - np.cos(u_spl(T))* s_spl(T)* u_spl_d(T)**2 \
                        -1/2.0* b* np.sin(u_spl(T))*u_spl_d(T)**2  \
                        + np.cos(u_spl(T))*s_spl_2d(T)\
                        + 1/2.0* b* np.cos(u_spl(T))* u_spl_2d(T) \
                        - s_spl(T)*np.sin(u_spl(T))*u_spl_2d(T)

    tstar_index = np.where(searching_for_zeros < 1e-25)[0][0]
    return tstar_index

def wurfparabel (x, v, beta):
    b = np.abs(beta)
    return - (x * np.tan(b) + (g * x**2)/(2* v**2* np.cos(b)**2))

def draw_bread(x_p, u, col):

    x_b = x_p + np.array([-b/2.0 * np.sin(u), -b/2.0 * np.cos(u)])
    x_left_down = x_b + np.array([-L/2.0 * np.cos(u), L/2.0 * np.sin(u)])
    x_left_up = x_left_down + np.array([b * np.sin(u), b * np.cos(u)])
    x_right_up = x_left_up + np.array([L * np.cos(u), -L * np.sin(u)])
    x_right_down = x_right_up + np.array([- b * np.sin(u), - b * np.cos(u)])

    plt.plot([x_b[0], x_left_down[0], x_left_up[0], x_right_up[0], x_right_down[0], x_b[0]], 
        [x_b[1], x_left_down[1], x_left_up[1], x_right_up[1], x_right_down[1], x_b[1]], col)


    pass

def find_nearest(array, value):
    array = np.asarray(array)
    idx = (np.abs(np.abs(array) - value)).argmin()
    return idx

def x_p(y):
    return np.array([y[:, 0] * np.cos(y[:, 2]) + b/2.0 * np.sin(y[:, 2]), 
                    - y[:, 0] * np.sin(y[:, 2] + b/2.0 * np.cos(y[:, 2]))
                    ])

plt.figure()
def test(T):

    def bread_falling_trajectory(v):
        """
        Function that calculates the trajectory of a piece of toast falling from a table with the initial velocity v.
        """

        # Define starting values. The  first value is chosen in such a way that the Center of mass is of the same hight as the zero point.
        ystart = np.array([np.sqrt(lstart**2+ (b/2.0)**2), v, 0.0, 0.0])

        x_sol_start = np.array([ystart[0] * np.cos(ystart[2]) + b/2.0 * np.sin(ystart[2]), 
                        - ystart[0] * np.sin(ystart[2] + b/2.0 * np.cos(ystart[2]))
                        ])

        # Define the right hand side of the differential equations.
        def rhs(y, t, g, L):
            return np.array([y[1], 
                            (1/(b**2 + L**2 + 24.0**y[0]**2))*
                            (6.0*b*g*np.cos(y[2])*y[0] - 7.0 *b**2 *g*np.sin(y[2]) - g* L*2.0 *np.sin(y[2]) - 24.0 *g *y[0]**2*np.sin(y[2]) 
                                - 24.0*b* y[0]* y[1]* y[3] - 8.0* b**2* y[0] * y[3]**2 - 2.0* L**2* y[0]* y[3]**2 - 48.0*y[0]**3* y[3]**2), 
                            y[3], 
                            -12.0*(-g *np.cos(y[2]) * y[0] + b* g* np.sin(y[2]) + 4* y[0] * y[1]* y[3] + b *y[0] *y[3]**2)/(b**2 + L**2 + 24 *y[0]**2)
                            ])

        # Solve the ODE
        y, data = odeint(rhs, ystart, T, full_output = True, args=(g, L))

        # Get the trajectory
        x_sol = x_p(y)

        #Find the index of x_sol at which the bread leaves the table.
        tstar_index = find_tstar_index(T, y)

        # Lösung ab Freier Fall
        # EQM is given by \ddot theta = 0, solving this and inserting the boundry conditions leads to winkel
        winkel = lambda zeit: y[tstar_index, 3] * zeit + y[tstar_index, 2]
        print(y[tstar_index, 3], y[tstar_index, 2] )

        # for the spatial part we essentially have a free falling rod, so we solve the eom and construct trajectory
        v0 = 1/2.0 * np.sqrt(4*y[tstar_index,1]**2 +4*b*y[tstar_index,1]* y[tstar_index,3] + (b**2 + 4*y[tstar_index,0]**2)*y[tstar_index,3]**2)
        beta = y[tstar_index, 2]
        trajectory_ = lambda x: wurfparabel(x, v0, beta)
        y_0 = np.abs(x_p(y)[1][tstar_index]-trajectory_(x_p(y)[0][tstar_index]))

        trajectory = lambda x: trajectory_(x)  + y_0


        # Creat a plot of the results 
        x_free_fall = np.linspace(x_sol[0][tstar_index], 0.45, N)

        sol_dict = {'x_sol_start': x_sol_start, 'table_traje': x_sol,
                    'x_free_fall': x_free_fall, 'free_fall_traj': trajectory(x_free_fall), 'y': y}

        return sol_dict, tstar_index, winkel



    for k, v in enumerate(vs):
        dicct, index, winkel = bread_falling_trajectory(v)
        # Plotting all the results
        #plt.subplot(3,1,k+1)
        plt.plot(dicct['x_sol_start'][0],dicct['x_sol_start'][1], "b*")
        # Plot the points where the bread leaves the table.
        plt.plot(dicct['table_traje'][0][index], dicct['table_traje'][1][index], "bo")
        # Plot the trajectroy up until this point
        plt.plot(dicct['table_traje'][0][:index+1], dicct['table_traje'][1][:index+1], label=r"$v$={}".format(v))
        # Draw the bread 
        draw_bread(dicct['table_traje'][:,0:index:100], np.pi/6.5 + dicct['y'][0:index:100,2], "g")

        x_p_free_fall = np.array([dicct['x_free_fall'],dicct['free_fall_traj']])

        spec_index = find_nearest(x_p_free_fall[1], table_hight)

        delta_T = T[-1]/N
        T_fall = np.linspace(0, spec_index * delta_T, spec_index)

        angle_free_fall = np.pi/6.5 + winkel(T_fall)

        draw_bread(x_p_free_fall[:,0:spec_index:100000], angle_free_fall[0:spec_index:100000], "r")


        # Plot the trajectroy after the bread has left the table
        plt.plot(dicct['x_free_fall'], dicct['free_fall_traj'])


        plt.ylim(-1.5, 0.1)
        plt.xlim(-0.1, 1.5)
        plt.plot(0.0, 0.0, "b*")
        plt.xlabel(r"$x$ [m]")
        plt.ylabel(r"$y$ [m]")
        plt.legend()


    return T_fall, winkel(T_fall)
N=1000000
ta, winekla = test(np.linspace(0,1,N))
tb, wineklb = test(np.linspace(0,10,N))
plt.show()
```

Note that the huge `test` function is just to play around with the different `T`.

---

**EDIT:** To illustrate the problem, two plots with different time samplings (N=1000,10000,...) and different time lengths (the first picture for T_end = 7s and the second one for T_end=10s).
[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you get a discontinuity when you change the step? Does the result converge for vanishingly small steps?

Comment: Give more information on the big picture: what you are trying to do, what results you get. Then move on to the code. Too many trees, too little forest.

Comment: @MathieuBouville I edited in as much context as I could (a full mathematical description of the problem).. To answer your fist questions: No discontinutiy, but not sure what you meant with your second question...

Comment: If you try steps of 1, 0.1, 0.01, 0.001, etc. do you eventually get a step-independent result?

Comment: @MathieuBouville The results seem to converge to some value for decreasing step size, but changing the end time produces completely different resutls

Comment: Can you show a plot of the results, e.g. different curves for different values of the step?

Comment: @MathieuBouville Done. Not sure how much one can see, but they bascly. overlap for $N>10'000$, meaning the Timestep is T_end/N.